# PHP email verification - wrong_code won't call proper action

Tags: php

I have the following email form:

```
    <form action="mailer.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" onsubmit="MM_validateForm('from','','RisEmail','name','','R','verif_box','','R','message','','R');return document.MM_returnValue">


     <table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#000000"><tr valign="top" align="right"> <td nowrap><font face="Verdana" size="3" color="#666666" >first name (<span class="R">*</span>)</font></td> 

    <td width="500" align="left"><input type="text" name="name" size="37" border="0" id="name" value="<?php echo $_GET['name'];?>"> </td></tr><tr valign="top" align="right"> <td nowrap><font face="Verdana" size="3" color="#666666">last name</font></td> 

   <td align="left"><input type="text" name="lastname" size="37" border="0" id="lastname" value="<?php echo $_GET['lastname'];?>"> </td></tr><tr valign="top" align="right"> <td nowrap><font face="Verdana" size="3" color="#666666">email (<span class="R">*</span>)</font></td> 

   <td align="left"><input type="text" name="from" size="37" border="0" id="from" value="<?php echo $_GET['from'];?>"> </td>
    </tr><tr valign="top" align="right"> <td nowrap><font face="Verdana" size="3" color="#666666"></font></td> 

  <td align="left"><input type=checkbox name="mailinglist" id="mailinglist" value="<?php echo $_GET['mailinglist'];?>"><font face="Verdana" size="3" color="#666666"></font><br> </td></tr><tr valign="top" align="right"> <td nowrap><font face="Verdana" size="3" color="#666666">comments (<span class="R">*</span>)</font></td> 

   <td align="left"><textarea name="message" cols="35" rows="10" border="0" id="message"><?php echo $_GET['message'];?></textarea><br> </td></tr><tr> <td colspan="2"><table cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0 bgcolor="#000000" width="100%"><tr bgcolor="#000000">

   <td class="label" colspan="2"><font color="#cccccc" face="Verdana" size="2"><b>Image Verification</b></font></td></tr><tr>

    <td> <input name="verif_box" type="text" id="verif_box" style="padding:2px; border:1px solid #CCCCCC; width:80px; height:14px;"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="verificationimage.php?<?php echo rand(0,9999);?>" alt="verification image, type it in the box" width="50" height="24" align="top" /><br />
    <br />

    <!-- if the variable "wrong_code" is sent from previous page then display the error field -->
    <?php if(isset($_GET['wrong_code'])){?>
    <div style="border:1px solid #990000; background-color:#D70000; color:#FFFFFF; padding:4px; padding-left:6px;width:295px;">Wrong verification code</div><br /> 
    <?php }?>


   </td><td class="field" valign="bottom">

  <div><input name="Submit" type="submit" style="margin-top:10px; display:block; border:1px solid #000000; width:100px; height:20px;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; padding-left:2px; padding-right:2px; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:2px; line-height:14px; background-color:#EFEFEF;" value="Send Message"/>

  <input type="reset" class="btn" value="  clear  " name="Clear" border="0" style="margin-top:10px; display:block; border:1px solid #000000; width:100px; height:20px;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; padding-left:2px;  padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:2px; line-height:14px; background-color:#EFEFEF;">

  </td></tr></table></td></tr></table></form>
```

and the following code in my mailer.php

```
    // check to see if verificaton code was correct
    if(md5($verif_box).'a4xn' == $_COOKIE['tntcon']){
// if verification code was correct send the message and show this page
mail("myemail@gmail.com", 'Online Form: '.$subject, "\n".$message." \n\n".$name."\n\n".$lastname."\n\n".$from."\n\n".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n\n".'mailinglist: '.$mailinglist, "From: $from");
// delete the cookie so it cannot sent again by refreshing this page
setcookie('tntcon','');
    } else if(isset($message) and $message!=""){
// if verification code was incorrect then return to contact page and show error
header("Location: http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}".dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."contactform.php?subject=$subject&email=$email&message=".urlencode($message)."&wrong_code=true"); 
exit;
    } else {
echo "no variables received, this page cannot be accessed directly";
exit;
}
    ?>
```

For some reason I receive emails when the verification code is correct, but the "wrong code warning" will not show up when the wrong verification code is entered.

Can someone help me please? I am new to php and it has taken me a long time just to get this to work. When the wrong verification code is entered, all that happens is that a blank mailer.php is called in the browser.

**sorry, not sure why the code copied in so many different windows.

Comment: There seems to be an extra `;` on the closing `}` on the first piece of code. Is that a typo while you were copying? Can you post the actual form of the email?

Comment: `<?php ;}?>` think that should be `<?php } ?>`. What is happening then, are you redirected to `..&wrong_code=true`?

Comment: @OhCaN That jumped out at me as well, but I just checked and that parses correctly and doesn't break anything (at least on 5.2.9-2/Win32) so I think that's a red herring

Comment: A side note on this, not going to fix the problem but still... Using relative paths in a `Location:` header is VERY bad practice and technically an HTTP protocol violation. ALWAYS use absolute paths when doing header redirects...

Comment: How would I use an absolute path? Also, most of the code was copied from a free source, so I am not surprised if there are errors in it.

Comment: For that particluar example, you could do `header("Location: http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}".dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."/contactform.php?subject=$subject&email=$email&message=".urlencode($message)."&wrong_code=true");`

Comment: @OhCaN where is the extra ; on the closing }

Comment: @Leah see Znarkus' comment above...

Comment: Okay, so I tried removing the extra ; and also changed the relative path to an absolute path and I still can't get it to work. Can someone take a look at [link]markreeder.ca/contactform.php[\link] and the respective mailer.php

Comment: @OhCaN or anyone else wondering, you can add as many semicolons as you want and make your code look like `exit;;;;;;;;;` if you really wanted too, it just looks funny. PHP will look at each semicolon as following an empty expression and do nothing, it's not syntactically incorrect.

Comment: I get a 200 back when I submit the wrong code, and don't get redirected. Try adding the line `header('HTTP/1.1 302 Found');` before the other `header()` call.

Comment: @DaveRandom thank you, but it still is not working?

Comment: @animuson yeh I just found that out by playing around with it, never bothered to before because, well, why would you? Although it does explain why you can follow a `}` closing a block with a `;` if your in JS mode and not paying attention, and it still works.

Comment: I guess this is a Nginx foible of some kind, and we will have to go with the cop-out solution. I will post an answer in a second cos it wont fit in a comment.

Comment: @animuson Thanks for the tip.--  Leah Replace the header() call with an `echo "Something";`. Does that something appear when you write the wrong verif code?

Comment: @DaveRandom, got your emails, made your changes to the header and published, but still getting a blank page when entering wrong verification code???

Comment: @OhCan, yes it does? Why is that?

Comment: For some reason your server does not seem to be letting you modify the HTTP headers. I did a Wireshark capture while I was playing with the page, and your `header()` call has no effect. See my answer below for a solution to this, albeit a nasty one if your a HTTP puritan like myself.

Comment: @DaveRandom, I wish I found this site hours ago. Thank you for your time, it is appreciated more than you realize. Your answer does exactly what the free code said it was supposed to. You're awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best idea would be to actually put the contents of `mailer.php` inside of `contactform.php`, so you wont need any redirects, no URL full of variables, no nothing.

The outcome of this would be something along the lines of:

```
<?php
$state = 0;
// check to see if verificaton code was correct
if(md5($verif_box).'a4xn' == $_COOKIE['tntcon']){
    // if verification code was correct send the message and show this page
    mail("myemail@gmail.com", 'Online Form: '.$subject, "\n".$message." \n\n".$name."\n\n".$lastname."\n\n".$from."\n\n".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n\n".'mailinglist: '.$mailinglist, "From: $from");
    // delete the cookie so it cannot sent again by refreshing this page
    setcookie('tntcon','');
    $state = 2;
} else if(isset($message) and $message!=""){
    // if verification code was incorrect then return to contact page and show error
    $state = 1;
}

if ($state == 0) {  ?>
    <form action="" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" onsubmit="MM_validateForm('from','','RisEmail','name','','R','verif_box','','R','message','','R');return document.MM_returnValue">

    <!-- All the form that I dont want to copy paste... -->

    </form>


<?php } else if ($state == 1) { ?>
       Message for wrong verification code.
<?php } else if ($state == 2) { ?>
       Message for email sent.
<?php } ?>
```

I changed the forms target attribute so it doesnt go to mailer.php and changed the opening php a bit to make it work with this distribution of things. You should change the input code to populate it with the POST data, instead of GET and you would avoid having that nasty looking URL.

Comment: If I changed all of this in my contactform.php - will it work in IE (as much as I hate internet explorer, still need it to work in all browsers). I mention this because DaveRandoms fix works in FF and Safari, but not IE.

Comment: +1 for this - I thought I'd keep it as simple as possible but as usual, IE has other ideas. @Leah, yes this *should* work everywhere, but then so should meta redirects, so really it's anyones guess... One point is that with this you will have to modify it so that your existing 'success' page is between the `<?php } else if ($state == 2) { ?>` and `<?php } ?>`

Comment: Also, how would I keep the rest of the page formating/styling remain the same if all you have added in here is the form data?

Comment: @Leah Yes, it would be crossbrowser since everything is resolved server-side. If youd like, show the full files and i can fully integrate the answer.

Comment: @DaveRandom, by golly I think I got it! I used the code above and managed to get it all to look the way I wanted it to. Tested it and it works like a charm! Thank you so much to both of you for all your hard work. I think I need to go to bed now too.

Comment: @OhCaN - Sorry to bother you months later, I have tried figuring this out on my own with no luck. I went to use this code again for another contact form on a different site and everything worked perfect (the required fields validation and success page) except the wrong verification code message won't show. So I went back to the original page that you helped me with where I know everything worked perfect - and wouldn't you know it, the verification error message stopped working. I could really use your help. Can't figure out why it stopped working or how to get it to work again. HELP?

Comment: @Leah Is the code exactly the same as mine? Anyway, if you haven't resolved it yet, you could open a new question. If you do, drop the link here and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @OhCan - it is exactly the same (or at least I believe it is). I started a new post here: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916758/php-emailer-redirect-not-working-for-verification-error) - also, the original one from here which was never changed also stopped working.

Comment: @OhCaN - Here you go (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930802/emailer-error-verification-message-stopped-working)

Comment: @OhCaN - have you had a chance to look at it yet? I could really use your help. I gave up trying and no one else seems to be able to help.

Comment: @DaveRandom - Can you read the last six comments here and tell me if you have any insight? I could really use some help.

Comment: @DaveRandom - can you check this out please? I am not having much luck with getting any answers... (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930802/php-email-form-wrong-verification-entered-message-not-working-anymore)

Answer (score 0):

In mailer.php, do this:

```
// check to see if verificaton code was correct
if (md5($verif_box).'a4xn' == $_COOKIE['tntcon']) {
  // if verification code was correct send the message and show this page
  mail("myemail@gmail.com", 'Online Form: '.$subject, "\n".$message." \n\n".$name."\n\n".$lastname."\n\n".$from."\n\n".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n\n".'mailinglist: '.$mailinglist, "From: $from");
  // delete the cookie so it cannot sent again by refreshing this page
  setcookie('tntcon','');
} else if (isset($message) && $message != "") {
  // if verification code was incorrect then return to contact page and show error
  exit("<html><head><title>Redirect</title><meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;contactform.php?subject=$subject&amp;email=$email&amp;message=".htmlspecialchars(urlencode($message))."&amp;wrong_code=true\" /></head><body>You should be redirected, if you aren't click <a href=\"contactform.php?subject=$subject&amp;email=$email&amp;message=".htmlspecialchars(urlencode($message))."&amp;wrong_code=true\">here</a>.</body></html>");
} else exit("no variables received, this page cannot be accessed directly");
```

Comment: wish I found this site hours ago. Thank you for your time, it is appreciated more than you realize. That does exactly what the free code said it would. You're awesome!

Comment: No worries, I must admit that's a problem I've never come across before, `header()` normally just sort of works, unless you do something really stupid, which you hadn't done. This solution lets the client handle the redirect, which possibly wont work in some v. old browsers but I would have thought it will be fine for your purposes. Right, I am now officially signing off and going to bed... :-)

Comment: I thought I was done with this but apparently IE has decided to show the thankyou.html page referenced in the correct validation code instead of the redirect? Safari and FF show it properly though (of course). Any ideas?

Comment: If you can face tackling it, use @OhCaN's solution because it is the better way to go. I have no idea why this would break in IE, especially in that way, but TBH it is 1am here, my brain is a bit shot and I'm going to feed the baby and go to bed rather than trying to work it out :-P

Comment: Okay, thank you. I hope I can understand it. I am going to assume I can enter the php code into the html so the page still keeps its current appearance. Wish me luck. If you do have any ideas later, tomorrow's a new day! Have a good night and thank you to everyone (again).

Comment: ...having said that, I have just updated the code above with a small fix (proper handling of HTML special chars) which *may* fix the problem, but I think it's kind of unlikely. And now I really am going to bed.