# PHP Emailer Redirect Not Working for Verification Error

Tags: php

Okay, I am a little confused because this code was working and for some reason has stopped. Not sure when it stopped working, but someone on this site created it for me and it was perfect when it worked. The person combined my mailer.php, redirect pages, and html code all in one awesome page. The successful page submitted works, but the incorrect verification code error spontaneously stopped working (?).

Here is the code:

```
 <?php
$state = 0;
// check to see if verificaton code was correct
if(md5($verif_box).'a4xn' == $_COOKIE['tntcon']){
// if verification code was correct send the message and show this page
mail("myemail@hotmail.com", 'Website Inquiry '.$subject, "\n\n".'Name: '.$name."\n\n".'Company: '.$company."\n\n".'Phone Number: '.$phone."\n\n".'Contact Me By: '.$ContactMethod."\n\n".'City: '.$city."\n\n".'I am Interested In: '.$InterestedIn."\n\n".'Comments: '.$comments."\n\n".$from."\n\n".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], "From: $email");
// delete the cookie so it cannot sent again by refreshing this page
setcookie('tntcon','');
$state = 2;
} else if(isset($message) and $message!=""){
// if verification code was incorrect then return to contact page and show error
$state = 1;
}

if ($state == 0) {  ?>

<form action="" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" onsubmit="MM_validateForm('email','','RisEmail','name','','R','verif_box','','R','comments','','R');return document.MM_returnValue">
```

#### Contact Form

Please complete the form below to have someone from our sales team contact you

```
  <p><strong>Tell us what you're interested in:</strong></p>

<dl>
  <dd>
<input type="radio" name="InterestedIn" value="BIBS<?php echo $_GET['InterestedIn'];?>"> Blow-In-Blanket System
    <input type="radio" name="InterestedIn" value="Spray Foam<?php echo $_GET['InterestedIn'];?>"> Soya Spray Foam
    <input type="radio" name="InterestedIn" value="Attic Insulation<?php echo $_GET['InterestedIn'];?>"> Attic Insulation
    <input type="radio" name="InterestedIn" value="Not Sure<?php echo $_GET['InterestedIn'];?>" checked="checked"> Not Sure</dd>
</dl>
<p><strong>Enter additional comments* in the space provided below:</strong></p>
<dl>
    <dd><textarea name="comments" cols="50" rows="5" border="0" id="comments"><?php echo $_GET['comments'];?></textarea></dd>
</dl>
<p><strong>Tell us how to get in touch with you:</strong></p>
<dl>
    <dd>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name*</td>
            <td>
            <input type="text" size="40" maxlength="256" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $_GET['name'];?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Company</td>
            <td>
            <input type="text" size="40" maxlength="256" name="company" value="<?php echo $_GET['company'];?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email*</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="40" maxlength="256" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $_GET['email'];?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Phone</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="40" maxlength="256" name="phone" value="<?php echo $_GET['phone'];?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>City</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="40" maxlength="256" name="city" value="<?php echo $_GET['city'];?>"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </dd>
</dl>
    <p><strong>Best method to get in touch with you:</strong></p>

<dl>
    <dd><input type="radio" name="ContactMethod" value="telephone<?php echo $_GET['InterestedIn'];?>" checked="checked">  Phone
    <input type="radio" name="ContactMethod" value="email<?php echo $_GET['InterestedIn'];?>"> Email
    </dd>
</dl>
```

" alt="verification image, type it in the box" width="50" height="24" align="top" />  
Enter Verification Image

```
<p style="padding-left:60px;"><input type="submit" class="button primary" value="Submit Form" name="submit"/>
<input type="reset" class="button primary" value="Clear Form" name"clear" /></p>
```

and then at the bottom of the page after the /html tag:

```
<?php } else if ($state == 1) { ?>
    <h3>Error</h3>
  <p>Wrong Verification Code Entered - Go back and try again</p>

<?php } else if ($state == 2) { ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

and then the rest of the html here... for the successful page submitted and then the closing php tag.

Any ideas why it stopped working? Any way to fix this with in the current code? If not, I need some way to tell the user of the form that they have submitted the wrong verification code. Currently, if you enter the wrong code it just refreshes the current page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am not well versed in php, so please use lamens terms!

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_validateForm() { //v4.0
var i,p,q,nm,test,num,min,max,errors='',args=MM_validateForm.arguments;
for (i=0; i<(args.length-2); i+=3) { test=args[i+2]; val=MM_findObj(args[i]);
if (val) { nm=val.name; if ((val=val.value)!="") {
  if (test.indexOf('isEmail')!=-1) { p=val.indexOf('@');
    if (p<1 || p==(val.length-1)) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain an e-mail address.\n';
  } else if (test!='R') { num = parseFloat(val);
    if (isNaN(val)) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain a number.\n';
    if (test.indexOf('inRange') != -1) { p=test.indexOf(':');
      min=test.substring(8,p); max=test.substring(p+1);
      if (num<min || max<num) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain a number between '+min+'  and '+max+'.\n';
} } } else if (test.charAt(0) == 'R') errors += '- '+nm+' is required.\n'; }
} if (errors) alert('The following error(s) occurred:\n'+errors);
document.MM_returnValue = (errors == '');
}
//-->
</script>
```

Verificationimage.php file code:

```
<?php
// ----------------------------------------- 
//  The Web Help .com
// ----------------------------------------- 

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$width = 50;
$height = 24;

$my_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

imagefill($my_image, 0, 0, 0xFFFFFF);

// add noise
for ($c = 0; $c < 40; $c++){
$x = rand(0,$width-1);
$y = rand(0,$height-1);
imagesetpixel($my_image, $x, $y, 0x000000);
}

$x = rand(1,10);
$y = rand(1,10);

$rand_string = rand(1000,9999);
imagestring($my_image, 5, $x, $y, $rand_string, 0x000000);

setcookie('tntcon',(md5($rand_string).'a4xn'));

imagejpeg($my_image);
imagedestroy($my_image);
?>
```

Comment: Seems to be a bit of code still missing. Can you provide more code?

Comment: @patrick - I will put in the rest of the code - didn't think it mattered.

Comment: I am trying to see where the tntcon cookie is getting set, but dont see it. Is there Javascript as well? The MM_validateForm function should be getting called on submit of the form.

Comment: @patrick - the form validates fine for required fields and shows the successful page when everything validates successfully, and the message for missing information from validation works, the only one that doesn't show "anymore" is the error from entering the wrong validation code in the verification box. I will check to see if he had given me javascript - it is possible but I don't recall.

Comment: @patrick - you may be right. Does this help:

Comment: You are only going to send an email if this is true: "md5($verif_box).'a4xn' == $_COOKIE['tntcon']". What you have posted does not show that cookie being set. Not sure what would have changed, but that is the missing piece of this puzzle. My guess is that MM_validateForm function sets it if all is valid.

Comment: @patrick - I edited the post to show javascript now. Please tell me if that helps. Nothing was changed from when it was working.

Comment: No, its not in there. Perhaps whatever service you are using for the verification code is what sets that cookie. It's also not showing where the $verif_box is getting defined. There must be more PHP code somewhere that is providing the verification code.

Comment: @patrick - if I wanted to remove the way this page calls the error message when the wrong verification code is entered and have it just post a message box to tell the person they entered the wrong code (similar to the validation currently being used for required fields), would you be able to help me achieve that?

Comment: @patrick - there is a verificationimage.php file which is called on by img src - but the post wouldn't let me include it because it thought it was an image file. Do you need to see that too? Or would my last comment be easier to do?

Comment: Can you post the code of the verificationimage php file?

Comment: @Patrick - added the file code to bottom of original post.

Comment: I still need help with this if someone can assist me? I still don't have a functioning way to give the user an error message if they enter the wrong verification code. Everything else works as it is supposed to. HELP???

Comment: Would you post the whole file in a single go, please? I'm not sure if things are missing or are just omitted.

Is this file included by some other file or is this it?

Comment: @OhCan - I will repost in a single instance separately - give me a minute. I will post link here when done.

Comment: @OhCan - here you go (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930802/emailer-error-verification-message-stopped-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verificationimage file was a big missing piece. That is where the cookie is being set. It looks like perhaps one line of code at the top of your script got removed accidentally and thus caused your problem. Unless it just wasn't copied in. I can't tell what the html field name of your verification image would be, but at the very top line you should have something like:

$verif_box = $_POST['verification_field'];

You are not setting the value for the $verif_box variable, so it will always fail.

Comment: Also just noticed, your form is doing a POST, but all your PHP variables are reading GET.

Comment: okay, it is finally not refreshing the page when the wrong code is entered, instead it keeps the remaining info and clears the field for the verification code. Unfortunately it still doesn't tell the person what the error is. I fixed the method from post to get. Do you know why my error message still doesn't show anymore?

Comment: Yes, because of this: "else if(isset($message) and $message!="")". Just like with $verif_box, $message variable is not being set either. Somehow that code is also missing.

Comment: I put the message in the "" and it still won't show. Also, I upon changing the method from post to get, two of my variables (radios) are pulling the same answer twice. I apologize if I am being a pain and I appreciate your help.

Comment: You would need to do $message = "test"; somewhere near the top...Are you sure there isn't more PHP code?

Comment: this was originally a free online contact form and php mailer. Someone on this site customized it for me to make it work properly. So I am assuming I have to put the $message "" in the verification image file, not the current file where the rest of the code is?

Comment: No, I would think it would go in the main file. But there needs to be logic that identifies what that message is. Something needs to do the check and determine that the code entered was incorrect. I don't see that anywhere

Comment: okay, I give up - tried everything you suggested and still can't get an error message to show. I tried adding the message in both php files (contact & image verification) and neither will show it when the wrong code is entered. At least the success message shows and the page doesn't refresh anymore when a wrong code is entered. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: the javascript checks the code I think? If not, I have no idea why nothing checks to see if the code is valid and I wouldn't know how to add it.